# Inherit Attributes inside a Facet in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can we allow the user access the attributes of a child component inside their body, like the index var of `aura:iteration`?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="item" indexVar="index">
    {!index} : {!item.FirstName}<br/>
</aura:iteration>
```

**Example** In this example I need to use the attribute `contact` in the `ComponentA` but the attribute is only defined on the `ListItem` component, just like `aura:iteration` that you don't need to define the `index` to use it:
ComponentA

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
   <c:list contacts="{!v.contacts}">
       <!-- Generic definition of how it's showed the listItem -->
       <!-- making available the contact var like the index var on aura:iteration -->
       <p>Name: {!contact.Name} </p>
   </c:list>
</aura:component>
```

List:

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
   <aura:attribute name="body" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
       <c:listItem contacts="{!contact}" body="{!v.body}"/>
   </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

ListItem:

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact"/>
   <aura:attribute name="body" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
   {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

**Another Example:**

Imagine a customLookup that allows the the developer using that generic component, to pass html inside the component to have a personalized list item.

Default usage `<c:customLookup apiName="Contact" selectedId="{!v.contactId}"/>`
Imagine the result of this equals than that salesforce offers as stardand.

But now, was gave other business requirement that the listItem of the Lookup looks diferent, with diferent fields etc. Example:

```
<c:customLookup apiName="Contact" aditionalFields="Email">
    <icon name="abc"/> this is my new list item {!contact.Email}
</c:customLookup >
```

Now, the customLookup will render with the new listItem passed by the developer, with the contact Email instead.

Comment: Would love to see an answer, but the last time I looked to this, I think I concluded that `aura:iteration` used a private API to accomplish this.